# When does a covariantly conserved tensor yield conserved quantities?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, conservation-laws

In special relativity, a conserved current is one that satisfies
$$\partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu \rho \ldots} = 0.$$
In this case, one can show that we have a tensorial conserved quantity
$$Q^{\nu \rho \ldots} = \int d^3x \, T^{0 \nu \rho \ldots}, \quad \frac{dQ}{dt} = 0.$$
In general relativity, a conserved current instead satisfies
$$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu \nu \rho \ldots} = 0.$$
Under what circumstances can we construct a tensorial conserved quantity? Is it always possible when $T$ has rank one? What conditions do we need when $T$ has rank greater than one?

Comment: some related posts: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177852/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40836/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218121/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225436/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175186/84967

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $J$ is a four vector satisfying $\nabla_a J^a =0$ and $\Sigma$,  $\Sigma'$ are smooth spacelike (Cauchy) hypersurfaces with the latter in the future of the former, it holds
$$Q := \int_\Sigma J^a n_a dS =  \int_{\Sigma'} J^a n'_a dS'\tag{1}$$
where $dS$ is the measure induced by the metric and $n$ the future-pointing unit co-vector normal to $\Sigma$ and similar definitions are valid for $\Sigma'$, provided $J$ rapidly vanishes at spacetime infinity. The proof is based on the divergence theorem referring to a cylindric surface $C$ with bases on $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$ respectively and lateral surface larger and larger towards spacelike infinity. Indeed, if $V$ is the solid cylinder whose frontiers is $\partial V = C $
$$0 = \int_V \nabla_aJ^a dv = \int_{\partial V} J^a N^a dS =  
 -\int_\Sigma J^a n_a dS +  \int_{\Sigma'} J^a n'_a dS' + 0\tag{2}$$
where $N$ is the outward normal unit vector to $C$ and  $0$ stays for the vanishing lateral contribution and we used the fact that $N = -n$ on $\Sigma$.
(2) immediately implies (1).

Now suppose that $T^{abcd...}$ is symmetric and $\nabla_a T^{abcd...}=0$. If $K,K',K'',...$ are Killing vectors (possibly equal) and we define $$J^a := T^{abcd...}K_bK'_cK''_d...$$
we have 
$$\nabla_aJ^a = \nabla_a (T^{abcd...}K_b K'_c K''_d...)$$ $$= (\nabla_a T^{abcd...})K_bK'_cK''_d...+ T^{abcd..} [(\nabla_aK_b) K'_c K''_d... +  K_b (\nabla_aK'_c) K''_d... + K_b K'_c  (\nabla_aK''_d)...]\:.$$ 
The right-hand side vanishes because $\nabla_a T^{abcd...}=0$ and, for instance, using $T^{abcd...}=T^{bacd...}$ 
$$ T^{abcd..} (\nabla_aK_b) K'_c K''_d... =  \frac{1}{2}T^{abcd..} (\nabla_aK_b + \nabla_bK_a)  K'_c K''_d... =0$$
in view of $$\nabla_aK_b + \nabla_bK_a=0$$
because $K$ is Killing.

In summary $$J^a := T^{abcd...}K_bK'_cK''_d...$$ defines a conserved charge if

(a) $\nabla_a T^{abcd...}=0$,

(b) $K,K',K'',...$ are Killing vectors (possibly equal)

(c) $J\to 0$ rapidly at spacelike infinity.

Condition (b) can be weakened to the requirement that some of the $K$s is a *conformal Killing vector* provided the corresponding trace of $T$ vanishes. E.g., if $K'$ is a conformal Killing vector it must also hold $T_{a}\:^{bad...}=0$.

Answer (score 5):

Any conserved $T^{ab\ldots c}{}_{;c} = 0$ and symmetric tensor $T^{ab\ldots c} = T^{(ab\ldots c)}$ gives rise to a conserved 4-current $J^a$ by contraction with Killing vectors, see e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/265452/118021) for the argument (the argument is essentially the same regardless of the tensor rank, as long as all but one index is contracted with a Killing vector). Alternatively, see Valter Moretti's answer. I will instead focus on the statement that $Q$ is constant.

By taking $Q = \int d^3x (J^an_a)$ for a time-like, unit normal field $n_a$, we find by the generalization of the Leibniz integral rule that 
$$
Q_{;a}n^a \equiv \dot{Q} = \int d^3x (J^bn_b)_{;a}n^a = \int d^3x\left(J^a\dot{n}_a + J_{a;b}n^an^b\right).
$$
By the same argument as in special relativity, we can replace the second term in the integrand by the 3-divergence, and convert it to a surface term via Stokes' Theorem on smooth manifolds (possibly by considering a limit). Thus if $J^a \to 0$ sufficiently fast as we approach infinity, so that the total flux goes to zero, and $\dot{n}_a = 0$ (or indeed if it is orthogonal to $J^a$) we find that $\dot{Q} = 0$.

Note that to the best of my knowledge the requirement that $J^a\dot{n}_a = 0$ cannot be circumvented, which becomes important if we consider the rest frame of an accelerated observer.