# Stationary spacetimes and metric tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

A stationary spacetime is defined to be one for which there exists a timelike Killing vector field such that the Lie derivative of the metric wrt this vector field vanishes,
i.e.

$\mathcal{L}_X g_{\mu\nu}=0$.

I would like to know what this implies for the properties of other quantities related to this spacetime.

Let's for example assume that we have some given action with a stationary spacetime acting as the background metric. The stress-energy tensor is then defined to be the variation of the action wrt the metric, i.e.

$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\sqrt{-g}}{2} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} $.

Will this energy-momentum tensor have properties linked to the stationarity?

All the best,

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366745/2451 and links therein.